# Using "skip_before_filter" in controller logs me out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller action that I need to call using AJAX.  So I used `skip_before_filter` to turn off the requirement that I be logged in for that particular call.

That works, but on subsequent requests, I get redirected to the login form.  How can I avoid this?

Here's the filter code in the controller:

```
protect_from_forgery
before_filter :logged_in?
skip_before_filter :logged_in?, :only => [:toggle_waiver]
```

Here's the controller action:

```
  def toggle_waiver
    @household = Household.find(params[:household_id])
    @household.update_attributes(:waive_latefee => params[:bool])
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

The `logged_in?` method is simply a home grown one:

```
def self.authenticate(username, password)
  user = find_by_username(username)
  if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    user
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to be doing this?  (I'm using Rails 3... don't judge me) :-)

Here's the `logged_in?` controller method (from the `application_controller`):

```
protected
def logged_in?
  unless session[:admin_id]
    flash[:notice] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to log_in_path
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

And the `session` is set by this method in the sessions controller:

```
  def create
    admin = Admin.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
    if admin
      session[:admin_id] = admin.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you please post your `logged_in?` controller method?

Answer (score 1):

You can make this much simpler by using the "except" clause of before_filter.

```
before_filter :logged_in, :except => [:toggle_waiver]
```

Also, "if a before filter renders or redirects, the action will not run. If there are additional filters scheduled to run after that filter they are also cancelled."  So ditch the true/false approach of your filter, and make it either render or redirect as the control of what happens.

Comment: My guess would be then that you are calling logged_in even when toggle-waiver is called (meaning filters are wrong).  That or you have a second logged_in function defined somewhere and IT is being called.  It's classic debugging that sometimes the reason something makes NO sense is because you're assuming something that's false - like that the logged_in function you showed above is actually what's called.

Comment: The call works to trigger the action.  It's just the call _after_ that that returns to the login page.  So somehow the session cookie is being dropped.